Error al Añadir Componente en VS 2022
He instalado VS comunity 2022 y me da un error al arrastrar cualquier componente en el formulario.
No da más mensajes que el que se ve "*Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto*".

Cuando sale el mensaje y pulso aceptar me deja añadir el componente pero si vuelvo a añadir otro componente pasa lo mismo.
Muchas gracias

Pulsa en [edit] y pon tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta el error que estás teniendo, como texto, con formato.

Parece que algo no se instalo correctamente.. probaste reinstalar o con otro proyecto?

he probado reinstalar todo VS, he probado en otro proyecto y sigue igual.
